# sample code for developing kidlogger for mac

Tags: cocoa

As i m a cocoa learner/beginner,can u give me a sample code for developing "kidlogger" in mac using cocoa application?

Comment: "Give me teh codez" questions don't generally invite helpful responses in communities like StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

No. Key loggers are serious/dangerous stuffs. Those who want to develop them should know what they are doing.

That said, let me give you one pointer: the part which reads the keystrokes is basically outside of Cocoa's ability. You should have a look at [Quartz Event Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).